# List hard Disk Information on remote computers within a domain

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am trying to get a list of hard disk information. At the moment I would only want the list to show the model of the hard disk that each computer contains.

I have the below

```
Get-WMIObject win32_diskdrive -computer (Get-Content C:\Temp\DiskDrives\Computers.txt) | Select model | Export- CSV "C:\Temp\DiskDrives\Machines.csv"
```

The computers.txt file contains a list of computers that the code goes through one by one. The above works to a point it will list the drives that it can find for a machine but the csv file is not formatted too well.

Can the csv be formatted to include the computer name from the txt file? also to only pick out hard disks and not usb, sd devices etc?

Appreciate any thoughts / advice.

Many Thanks,
Chris

Comment: see [psexec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [invoke-command](http://ss64.com/ps/invoke-command.html) you can use powershell `invoke-command` and use pipeline and `out-file c:\example.csv`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just pick out the SystemName property as well, and you'll get a result like this.

```
Get-WMIObject win32_diskdrive -computer (Get-Content C:\Temp\DiskDrives\Computers.txt) | `
  Select SystemName,model 

>SystemName Model                              Size(GB)
---------- -----                              --------
BEHEMOTH   OCZ-VERTEX PLUS R2                       58
BEHEMOTH   JetFlash Transcend 32GB USB Device       29
BEHEMOTH   INTEL SSDSC2CT180A3                     168
BEHEMOTH   SAMSUNG HD103SJ                         932
BEHEMOTH   OCZ-VERTEX                               60
BEHEMOTH   ST3000DM001-1CH166                     2795
BEHEMOTH   OCZ-VERTEX PLUS R2                       58
BEHEMOTH   JetFlash Transcend 32GB USB Device       29
BEHEMOTH   INTEL SSDSC2CT180A3                     168
BEHEMOTH   SAMSUNG HD103SJ                         932
BEHEMOTH   OCZ-VERTEX                               60
BEHEMOTH   ST3000DM001-1CH166                     2795
```

As soon as you run a WMI query against more than one machine, you also get the SystemName parameter too, which makes this easy!

Note that in my above result, I've got a small drive called Transcend, which is a 32 GB USB 3 FlashDrive.  You mentioned wanting to include only Fixed disks, not USB, so to do that we just add in a Where Statement, like this:

```
PS C:\> Get-WMIObject win32_diskdrive -ComputerName behemoth,localhost | 
Where-Object MediaType -eq 'Fixed hard disk media' | Select SystemName,Model

>SystemName Model               Size(GB)
---------- -----               --------
BEHEMOTH   OCZ-VERTEX PLUS R2        58
BEHEMOTH   INTEL SSDSC2CT180A3      168
BEHEMOTH   SAMSUNG HD103SJ          932
BEHEMOTH   OCZ-VERTEX                60
BEHEMOTH   ST3000DM001-1CH166      2795
BEHEMOTH   OCZ-VERTEX PLUS R2        58
BEHEMOTH   INTEL SSDSC2CT180A3      168
BEHEMOTH   SAMSUNG HD103SJ          932
BEHEMOTH   OCZ-VERTEX                60
BEHEMOTH   ST3000DM001-1CH166      2795
```

Bonus points, if you want to show the size of the disk in GB, change your select statement to this, which uses a calculated property to make a new column called Size(GB) and populate it with the $_.Size property divided by 1GB in integer (whole number) form :

```
Select SystemName,Model,@{Name='Size(GB)';Exp={$_.Size /1gb -as [int]}}`
```

**Completed One-Liner**

Simply add your Export-CSV to the end of the pipeline to have a completed one-
liner like this which should give you the results you're looking for:

```
Get-WMIObject win32_diskdrive -computer (Get-Content C:\Temp\DiskDrives\Computers.txt) | 
Where-Object MediaType -eq 'Fixed hard disk media' | 
Select SystemName,Model,@{Name='Size(GB)';Exp={$_.Size /1gb -as [int]}} |
Export- CSV "C:\Temp\DiskDrives\Machines.csv"
```

Ahh, the Power of PowerShell.

Comment: thanks for the information and the detail you have given. This is what I was looking for and works well, the formatting of the data makes it much easier to read. Appreciate the effort you have gone to.